# Problems with SQL query. Select row with max() column

Tags: sql

You need to get the username or usernames with the maximum number of integrations.

ER Diagrams[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cRsK.png)

Try One:

```
SELECT username 
FROM 
    (SELECT au.username, COUNT(DISTINCT ci.integration_name_id) AS max_ini 
     FROM auth_user au 
     RIGHT JOIN card_integrations as ci ON au.id = ci.user_id 
     GROUP BY au.username) T 
ORDER BY T.max_ini DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Problems if there are several users with the maximum number of integrations.

Try Two (Scripts):

```
set @m = (SELECT MAX(i) FROM 
(SELECT au.username as u, COUNT(DISTINCT ci.integration_name_id) as i FROM auth_user au
RIGHT JOIN card_integrations as ci ON au.id = ci.user_id
GROUP BY au.username) T);

SELECT u FROM (SELECT au.username as u, COUNT(DISTINCT ci.integration_name_id) as i FROM auth_user au
RIGHT JOIN card_integrations as ci ON au.id = ci.user_id
GROUP BY au.username) T WHERE i = @m;
```

Not optimal

Please help me, sorry for the English.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want window functions:

```
SELECT username 
FROM (SELECT au.username, COUNT(DISTINCT ci.integration_name_id) as max_ini,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT ci.integration_name_id) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM auth_user au JOIN
           card_integrations ci
           ON au.id = ci.user_id 
      GROUP BY au.username
     ) T 
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  Assuming that there is at least one "integration", then an outer join is not needed.